# NodeJs Read line by line and next line

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using the Node readline module to read files line by line whilst checking for certain conditions in eachline. However the files are inconsistent in line breaks. Sometimes the line will break into the next line causing the if condition to not catch. Is there a way to to check the nextline while in the current line? Much appreciated with any help. Thanks!

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function processLineByLine() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
  // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.

  for await (const line of rl) {
    // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
    if(line.includes('abc') && nextline.includes('def')) {
     
  }
}

processLineByLine();
```

Sample input

one-line

```
<ref href="sample.txt">
```

two-line

```
<ref 
href="sample.txt">
```

Comment: This is a very backwards question as a line break.. ie text spanning from one line to the next line, is itself a NEW LINE. not simply the same line continued. if your text is spanning multiple lines then you need to conduct a more thorough search instead of just checking a single line

Comment: agreed. however the files I'm receiving is inconsistent in line breaks. Some would be in one line, some would be in two. However I need to validate everything on that one or two line to perform an operation.

Comment: Probably provide an example of the input.  Show what broken and unbroken lines look like right in your question.

Comment: then searching line by line is not the answer, buffer up a few lines or just read the whole file in at once

Comment: updated with sample input.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
  let previousLine;
  for await (let line of rl) {
    // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
    // check if current line fulfils your conditions
    // if not and previousLine has value check conditions with the 2 lines 
    // if not you store current line into previousLine 
    previousLine = line;
  }
```